# Question on congruences

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Let $b\equiv c\equiv 0$ modulo a prime number $p$. Let $d \equiv 1$ modulo $p$. Say $b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}/p^e \mathbb{Z}$

Is it clear that there is a *unique* $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^e \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$ad-bc = 1 \quad ?$$

I do not quite see how uniqueness can be independent of the $p^e$ power chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Because $\gcd(d, p^e)=1$ so $d$ is invertible and you can solve

$$a = (1+bc)d^{-1}.$$